# How to calculate the avg time a tool stays on hold? oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to calculate the average time a tool stays on loan. The time a tool stays on loan is the number of days between loan_status_change_date and tool_out_date (table columns). the date type of these 2 columns is ex: 01-SEP-17
whats the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do arithmetic with Oracle dates. It's not clear from the column names which one is the start of the loan and which the end; in the following example I've assumed `loan_status_change` is when the tool is returned.

```
select tool
     , avg(loan_status_change - tool_out_date) as avg_loan_days
from   your_table
group by tool
/
```

---

The AVG() function is an aggregate function, so it handles the `/ns` for us. The substraction is to calculate the length of a particular loan, which is the value you want to average. The result of that substraction already is a number of days, so no further transformation is necessary. If your columns have a time element then the result might not be an integer.

Comment: Thank you APC! Question. I know the avg of something is n+n1+../ns. Why are we subtracting it here? Also, if I wanted the results to be in days, would I have to use To_date to transform this result?

Comment: @Socramvm `loan_status_change - tool_out_date` gives the number of days between `loan_status_change` and `tool_out_date`. We want the average of that.